# How to Format Chinese Address?

Tags: word-choice, writing, formal

I have something to return on Aliexpress and the seller provided this address:

"Liu Kai
China Guangdong Province Dongguan Shatian Town san sheng cun yan he lu 50 hao er lou
CN 523000 Dongguan Guangdong Province"

Can someone please let me know how to format this address for shipping from the US?

Answer (score 1):

Receiver name: Liu Kai

Receiver address: 50 Yan He Road 2nd floor, San Sheng Village, Shatian Town, Dongguan City, Guangdong Province, China 523000